# Android map api v2 - Marker click-events are delayd

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm using a MapFragment with a listener for marker clicks. I noticed there's a delay between tapping a marker and the listener being called. 
Tested using a minimal empty project with nothing but this code (+ some boilerplate), that's from my activity:

```
mapFragment.getMap().setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
        Log.d("MarkerTest", "dispatchTouchEvent");
        return true;
    }
});


@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    Log.d("MarkerTest", "dispatchTouchEvent");
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
}
```

And indeed, there's a consistent 250-300 ms delay between the logs. Usually 250 millis are not a big deal, but in my use case it really hurts the experience. 
Any chance it's related to the infamous browsers' 300 ms issue? Does anyone know how to get rid of this delay?

Note: I've tested on genymotion emulator, nexus 5 and note 4 using the latest maps api (play services 7.8) - same behavior across the board.

Comment: Same issue here. 
I ended up turning off marker clicks and used a GestureDetector in dispatchTouchEvent. A hack, yes, but the experience is clearly better.

Also: Why the downvote? It's a legitimate question!

Comment: Same here, using touch listeners instead of map click events. It's pretty ugly but I couldn't come up with anything better yet.